# How to invert spin_lock_init

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, spinlock

I'm trying to understand how to use the Linux kernel spinlocks. From reading the header, I think I have to first declare one and initialize it like this with [`spin_lock_init`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/include/linux/spinlock.h#L330):

```
spinlock_t xxx_lock;
spin_lock_init(&xxx_lock);
```

and then I can lock and unlock it with [`spin_lock`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/include/linux/spinlock.h#L336) and [`spin_unlock`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/include/linux/spinlock.h#L376).

I hope what I understood until here is correct.
But what do I have to do to "invert" the `spin_lock_init`? How do I destroy the spinlock?

Comment: Look up the type.  Maybe it's just a plain, ordinary data struct and so does not need an explicit destructor function?  'Init' probably just initializes it's fields.

Comment: Not an answer to the question but I see that they can also be defined with a macro: `DEFINE_SPINLOCK(xxx_lock)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A spinlock doesn't require special finalization function (destructor).

When a spinlock is *unlocked*, it isn't used by the kernel internally. So, if you don't intend to use an unlocked spinlock anymore, just forget about it.